# Modify the linked list such that each element can store a pointer to another linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I have implemented the linked list class however I am not sure how to go about making it point to another linked list. I want to have it so that within the same class to have 3 pointers. One for data, one for next and lastly one for the other linked list.

Can someone point to me in the right direction.

**Header File**

```
class Node{

public:
    typedef int value_type;
    //COSTRUCTOR- get two values link and positive integer
    Node(const value_type& i_data = value_type(), Node *i_link= nullptr) //value_type()=0 //Constructor
    {
        this->data_field = i_data;
        this->link_field= i_link;
    }
    //Member functions to set the data and next;
    void set_data(const value_type& new_link);
    void set_next(Node *new_next);
    //Constant member function to retrieve the current data:
    value_type get_data()const;
    //Two slightly different members functions te retrieve current link
    Node* get_next();
    const Node* get_next() const;
    //friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Node& p);
private:

    Node* link_field;
    value_type data_field;

};
size_t LinkedList_size(const Node* headptr);
void LinkedListInsertAtHead( Node*& headptr, const Node::value_type& entry);
//   LinkedList_insert_at(list,input, 99);
void LinkedList_insert_at( Node*& headptr, int index, const Node::value_type& entry);
void LinkedList_delete( Node*& headptr);
void LinkedList_delete_from(Node*& headptr,int index);
void LinkedList_print(const Node* headptr);
```

**Implementation File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "node.h"
// Node(const value_type& data, Node* next);//consturctor

void Node::set_data(const value_type& new_data) { this-> data_field = new_data; }
void Node::set_next(Node* new_next)             { this-> link_field = new_next; }
Node::value_type Node::get_data() const      { return this-> data_field; }
           Node* Node::get_next()            { return this-> link_field; }
     const Node* Node::get_next() const      { return this-> link_field; }

size_t LinkedList_size(const Node* headptr) //point to a const node
{
    ///  Node* = {[n1] [n2] [n3] [n4] [n5] [n5] } ,@t first: headptr = n1;
    ///  curr = n1;    curr = headptr
    ///  curr = n1->n2,  curr= curr-> headptr
    size_t count = 0;
    for(const Node* curr = headptr; curr != nullptr; curr = curr->get_next())
    {
    count++;
    }
    return count;
}
void LinkedListInsertAtHead( Node*& headptr, const Node::value_type& entry)
{
    //0->0->0->null
    headptr = new Node(entry, headptr);//inserts and return a new address

}

void LinkedList_insert_at( Node*& headptr, int index, const Node::value_type& entry)
//0->O->O ->O
//insert_at(0):   N->->O->O ->O
//insert_at(1):   O->O->O->O ->O
//insert_at(n=4): O->O->O->O ->N
{
    if(index==0){
        LinkedListInsertAtHead(headptr, entry);
        return;
    }
    Node* node_before = nullptr;
    Node* node_after = headptr;//->get_next();

    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    {
        node_before = node_after;

        node_after = node_after->get_next();
    }

    Node* insert_node= new Node(entry, node_after);

    node_before->set_next(insert_node);

}
void LinkedList_delete( Node*& headprt)
// 36[data] 46[dat] 94[data] [] [] [] []
{
    Node* curr = headprt; //delete [data] and address"36"

    headprt = headprt->get_next();//assign to ->46[data]
    delete curr;

}

void LinkedList_delete_from(Node*& headptr,int index)
{
    if(index==0)
    {
    LinkedList_delete(headptr);
    return;
    }

    Node* node_before = nullptr;
    Node* curr = headptr;//->get_next();  //curr short for current

    for(int i=0; i<index; ++i)
    {
    node_before = curr;
    curr = curr->get_next();
    }

    node_before->set_next(curr->get_next());

    delete curr;

}

void LinkedList_print(const Node* headptr)
{
/*    THIS  DOES THE SAME;
    const Node* temp = headptr;
    while(temp!= nullptr)
    {
        //cout insertion operator

       std::cout << temp->get_data() <<" ";
        temp = tempp->get_next();///will connect to next data []->get_next(return this->[next])->[]->nullptr

    }
   */
while(headptr != nullptr)
{

    std::cout << headptr->get_data()<<" ";
    headptr = headptr->get_next();///will connect to next data []->get_next(return this->[next])->[]->nullptr

}

std::cout<<std::endl;//to skip a line

}
```

Comment: Well, you only implemented a `Node` class. If you want to point to a `LinkedList`, you need to have such a class first.

Comment: Same problem you had last time you asked this question. Same solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your issue is with a forward declaration:

```
// Forward declarations
class Linked_List;
class Data;

class Node
{
  Linked_List * p_linked_list;
  Data *        p_data;
  Node *        p_next;
};
```

The method implementations will need the definitions for `Data` and `Linked_List`.